# What is the default date format Swift uses for JSONEncoder?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, jsonencoder

```
struct TestEnc: Codable {
    var date = Date()
}
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let tenc = TestEnc()
let jsonData = try encoder.encode(tenc)
let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print("json:\(json)")
```

This prints:

```
json:Optional("{\"date\":589331953.61679399}")
```

I can't find what this is supposed to represent in the documentation.

Comment: Please read [The Codable Cheat Sheet](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet)

Comment: @vadian The cheat sheet does not mention Date encoding at all. Only decoding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS date are often encoded or processed as seconds from `ReferenceDate`

e.g.
`Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:)`

Documentation for this is:

> Summary
>
> Creates a date value initialized relative to 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001 by a given number of seconds.

Can run your number through this, and you will get your date back:

`Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 589331953.61679399)`

> output: "2019-09-04 23:19:13 +0000\n"

---

As far as the explicit *encoding* documentation goes. This is pretty terse.

There is a reference to the default encoding strategy in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2895363-dateencodingstrategy) saying:

> The default strategy is the JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy.deferredToDate strategy.

However, there doesn't seem to be any clarity on what this actually means (beyond manual testing), reference is currently [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/dateencodingstrategy). Even digging into the interface files, there doesn't seem to be any more light.